the forces in each member using the method of joints. support at A hinged and support at B is roller
Determine the forces in each member using the method of joints support at A hinged and support at B is roller.]1

You need to show your work so far, then people may help with corrections or hints  - we are not a free homework completion service.

As you say in your question, you need to use the method of joints to solve this. Take a look here: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mechanical_Engineering/Mechanics_Map_(Moore_et_al.)/05%3A_Engineering_Structures/5.04%3A_Method_of_Joints
